# Dijit.Tree with dndController confirm dialog on dropping item

Tags: drag-and-drop, tree, dojo

I want ask user for confirming drop item in dijit.Tree

How implement this?

My solution

```
dojo.declare('myDnDSource', dijit.tree.dndSource, {
    onDndDrop: function() {
      if (confirm('Yes/No?')) {
        return this.inherited(arguments);
      } else {
        return this.onDndCancel();
      }
    }
  });
```